# Time shifted when parsing csv file

Tags: apache-spark

I have a csv file with timestamp per record (row). I'm parsing it using spark csv (I'm including it into Spark 1.5.2) but a strange thing happens.

All the timestamps from my file are shifted by 3 hours. For example, I have values starting from `2015-12-27 00:00:00` and ending with `2016-12-28 00:00:00`. Now, when I parse this using Spark I get values from range `2015-12-27 03:00:00` till `2015-12-28 03:00:00`.

Why is this happening and what is the best way to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with time zone on server being different than UTC. That messed up parsing, adding the 3 hours during parse.